abc → acb → aaa → aaa → aaa

abc → acb → aaa → aaa → aaa
bcd → cbd → ddd → ddd → ddd
abcd → acac → acac → acac → acac
habit → baiai → aabai → aaaaa → aaaaa

In the above examples, the words have been transformed according to the logic of the
code four times. When the word “TECHNICHE” undergoes the same logical transformation
thrice, what is the word that one obtains?
A) EineeneihB) EeeiheieeC) HeieeeeeiD) Ieeeeeihe
Source: IIT Technothlon 2014 (Question 10)

Hi, and welcome to Puzzling. Please could you provide the source for this puzzle (i.e. where you found it)? This way the original content creator can be credited, as per site policy. Thank you.

@Stiv, let's not assume that the OP found this puzzle somewhere, maybe he created this puzzle himself. Either way, it's a good puzzle :)

@Lezzup Okay, but 99 times out of 100 this type of question will be from another source. Experience from this community over time suggests that people tend not to create problems of this form just for publishing here; they usually come from an external IQ test, job application, piece of homework, or another recreational website. Assuming it is from elsewhere does not come with any stigma or negative energy if the remark is written nicely - it's just statistically the most efficient way to ask for a source. Either way, I respect the motivation behind your comment :)

@Stiv, you're probably right about the 99%, I know from experience myself. And I would like to see that changed. But a new user doesn't know that. And if he did create this puzzle himself, the question is a bit unfortunate.

Perhaps a question more in line with suggesting an author be provided if one such exists, rather than assuming the question come from another author automatically, would achieve the same purpose.

@TakingNotes Believe me, there's no right answer here! :) I tend to mix and match the tone and content of my comments when I post this remark because sometimes when I'm direct someone comments to say I'm being too direct/mean/cynical, and sometimes when I leave it more open someone else comments to say I'm being too handwavey/naive/gullible. Ultimately, it's a case of: Comment to ask for attribution, and hope for the best...! Anyway, let's wait to see what the OP says, I guess.

The answer is

 C.

Transformation rule:

 Let f(a)=0,f(b)=1,f(c)=2,etc.
 
 Replace each letter l with the letter f(l) positions ahead wrapping around if necessary.

Applied to test case:

 
       T  E  C  H  N  I  C  H  E
      19  4  2  7 13  8  2  7  4
 



 Now, to replace the "T" we need to look 19 places ahead.
 As the word has only 9 letters this involves 2x wrapping around and yields "E"
 To replace the next letter, "E", we need to look 4 ahead which gives "I". For the next, "C", it is 2 ahead, "N". Etc.
 Continuing like that we get



 
        E  I  N  E  E  N  E  I  H
 


Applying the same procedure two more times we obtain the stated answer.

This answer is too sparse for me to understand could you perhaps elaborate?

Oh forget it I see the logic

Jesus this is genius

@JirhsKumar I guess it's not your own puzzle then? :)

@sarsaparilla I've added the source to the post
